# SEO/PHP: How to Convert Form-Submit URL (Get-Method) without Javascript SEO-Friendly?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, seo

and actually i convert the url with javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.search-form').submit(function() {

        var value = $('.search-form input:text').val();
        value = value = value.replace(/\W/,''); // replace
        window.location.href = value + "-keyword" + ".html";
     return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

is there a method to convert the url seo-friendly without javascript? maybe with php?

Comment: You could always accept the POST at index.php and 301 redirect to <searchkeyword>-keyword.html from there.  The only reason to change the action attribute in-page is if you want to save a request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am for the following technique because

1. it's a guessable URI to search "via the address bar"
2. it's always a good thing to redirect while responding to a POST-request, to avoid awkward "want to send POST information again?"-alerts when the user tries to go back via the browser's back button
3. it's simply easier to see what I searched for if the URI is clean of hidden values, value of submit-button etc.

Here goes:

```
<?php
//receiving page
if(isset($_GET['name_of_submit'], $_GET['search_phrase'])) {
    header("Location: /address_to_this_script/".$_GET['search_phrase']);
    die;
}
if(isset($_GET['search_phrase'])) {
   // handle search and validation here, don't forget to escape it!
}
```

Comment: Note that FORMS actions are not detectable by bots, TBMK. So this would be useful only when users copy-past URL as a link. Otherwise, you need to publicate those links at crawled pages (a most-visited page and a related box would do the trick).

Comment: Correction: At 2008 Google start to test experimental FORM web crawling, only in high rated sites. I don't know if that continues. Still, my recomendation is easy and useful.

Comment: I'm not sure I reflected on the tucked-on-at-the-end "SEO-friendly" part of the question. I wouldn't know how my answer affects SEO in practice, it's rather based on "usability". Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do too, because if anyone links to either URL the link juice will always flow down in the SEO Url eventually. You could use an onclick to take the user to an SEO URL in javascript, but google wont follow it.

One thing you could do is to store those searches in a db and then have them as "related links" (the seo versions) linked to from each page on your site, this way they will get spidered.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to remove special characters and replace it by the page, category and section names. Regards