# PHP form submit button in $_GET

Tags: php, forms, get, friendly-url

I have a form that submits a search for blogs on my site via GET.

The form works fine, but when submitted, the url on the following page reads ("Find it" is the value of my submit button):

> www.example.com/search.php?sub_q=Find+it%21&q=tennis

This just isn't an aesthetically pleasing url. Is there a simple way to exclude the submit button from the URL? I would like the url to look like:

> www.example.com/search.php?q=tennis

The search.php doesn't require $_GET['sub_q'] to operate, btw.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try not naming your button (remove the `name` attribute) - it shouldn't be submitted if it doesn't have n name

Answer (score -2):

See my answer here: [SEO/PHP: How to Convert Form-Submit URL (Get-Method) without Javascript SEO-Friendly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367987/seo-php-how-to-convert-form-submit-url-get-method-without-javascript-seo-frien/2382086#2382086)

Basically: redirect to an easier-to-spell-out-URI