# Is it normal for the Submit button to show in $_POST data?

Tags: php, post

Is it normal for the Submit button to show in $_POST data?

I have a form and when I var_dump the $_POST data the submit button is showing up. I'm sure I have never had this before, but, I could also be losing it.

Comment: Yes, you are losing it. The submit button usually shows. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP form submit button in $_GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382208/php-form-submit-button-in-get)

Comment: Cheers all, I knew I was losing it. To long on front-end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it normal for the Submit button to show in $_POST data?

Yes. Submit buttons are [regular controls in HTML forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#submit-button).

The button's value will be transmitted along with the form data.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal and expected. all inputs, (text, button, submit) should be present, except for checkboxes that are off, and disabled fields.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal, because submit button also has it's value atribute like all other input elements (it is a text which you see on the button, like 'OK' or 'Submit')..